# How change the default application for "Edit" and "Print" actions from context menu in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, printing, configuration, registry, default

I have two computers with windows xp on it (maybe the windows version doesn't matter, but anyway):

- On the first I click **print** and then it opens the print preview in the NotePad++
- On the second it opens in the standard MS Notepad, which cannot handle a big file

I don't know, how it was configured on the first computer to make a print preview in the NotePad++, but I would like to have the same on the second computer as well.

Are there any settings/registry keys to define? I already searched the registry with regedit to find - where NotePad++ is set as default app, but nothing related to printing service.

Does somebody know how to set Notepad not only as the default program to open the file (this is easy), but **how to set it as a default printing preview program** as well?

## Update 1:

just right now found that the same setting could be for the Edit parameter (from the context menu, i.e. right mouse clic -> Edit)

## Update 2:

sounds similar to this problem: [http://superuser.com/questions/68852/change-windows-7-explorer-edit-context-menu-action-for-jpg-and-other-image-fil]
But I don't want install third party app. It should be configured with the standard options, I think

Answer (score 4):

First determine the file type of your file - lets say myfile.foo:

```
assoc .foo
```

This wil output something like

```
.foo=foofile
```

Then open regedit and navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\foofile\shell`. There you will see subkeys like `open\command` and `print\command`. Change the default value of the print command to whatever you like and you are done.

Comment: This is not the answer on the question. A man wanted to change Edit action.